# What is wrong with my namespace declaration in this clojure project?

Tags: clojure, namespaces, middleware, leiningen, ring

I am using Clojure and leinigen to build a backend project.

This is a simplified version of my file:

```clj
(ns simplified...
  (:require [ring.middleware.json :refer [wrap-json-response]]
            [ring.util.response :refer [response]]
            [ring.middleware.json :refer [wrap-json-body]]
            [ring.middleware.defaults :refer [wrap-defaults]]
            [ring.adapter.jetty :as jetty]))

(defroutes rest-api-routes
  (POST "/api" req
        
        (clojure.pprint/pprint req)
        "hello"))

(defn import-atb
  [request-id tenant-id]
  (let [trial-balance-report  (middleware/wrap-json-body rest-api-routes {:keywords? true})])
  trial-balance-report)
```

After doing a `lein clean`, when I run `lein repl`, I get:

```bash
#error {
 :cause No such namespace: middleware
```

What is wrong with my file?

Comment: Before you can write `middleware/wrap-json-body`, you need `:as middleware` in one of your require vectors. Though, it looks like you've already tried to `:refer` `wrap-json-body`, so, maybe just change `middleware/wrap-json-body` to `wrap-json-body`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick fix is to substitute `middleware/wrap-json-body` for `wrap-json-body` because it's been referred into the namespace.

`require` can take an `:refer` option. The `:refer` option, which you're using here, allows you to refer to that namespace's var directly from your own. The `:as` option will allow you to alias a namespace within your own. For example, you could `(:require [ring.middleware.json :as ring-json])` and then refer to `ring-json/wrap-json-body` in your namespace.